# How to subset an object based on the property values in an array in typescript/angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I am learning typescript. I wonder what is the best way to subset object based on the property values from another array.

For example, I have following object and array:

```
const Aobject = 
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "id": "city_id1",
      "name": "NY"
    },
    {
      "id": "city_id2",
      "name": "BOS"
    },
    {
      "id": "city_id3",
      "name": "SF"
    },
    {
      "id": "city_id4",
      "name": "LA"
    }
   ]
}

const Aarray = ["city_id2", "city_id3"]
```

Expected output (array):

```
[
  {
    "id": "city_id2",
    "name": "BOS"
  },
  {
    "id": "city_id3",
    "name": "SF"
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post some code you've attempted?

Comment: Why is `Aobject` wrapped in double quotes? That isn't valid. If it is an object, just use `Aobject.cities.filter(c => Aarray.includes(c.id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
result = [];

subSetArray() {
this.Aobject.cities.forEach(x => {
  this.Aarray.forEach(z => {
    if (x.id.includes(z)) {
      this.result.push(x);
    }
  });
});
console.log(this.result);
}
```